# What are the differences between the models A and A+?

Tags: pi-a, pi-a+

There are minor hardware differences between Model A (as released 2012) and Model A+ (as released 2014).

What are they and what things can be done with an A+ the cannot be done with the A? Does peripheral changes prevent the use of certain expansion boards? Are there advantages to use the older model A over the new A+ (Bonus: is the model A still available)?

Comment: The original model A isn't being made anymore, but the original model B is. You would still be able to get the model a from a third-party distributor who has stock, but it would probably be more expensive than buying a new model A+.

Comment: @angussidney my experiance is that the model A is practically unobtainable nowadays. The last person I talked to who found a reseller claiming to have stock ended up with an old 256MB model B.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several notable differences between the RPi A, and A+. According to the official [release](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-a-plus/), the differences are as follows:

1. **An expanded GPIO header**. The A+ has 40 pins which considerably larger than the original 26. Additionally, the new form factor and I2C compatibility allow standard Raspberry Pi [hats](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/) to be used with the A+ model.
2. **MicroSD**. The A+ switched from a standard SD card to a MicroSD card as its primary storage medium.
3. **Less Power**. The A+ has significantly lower power consumption due to more efficient circuitry.
4. **Better Audio**. The new circuit has a dedicated low-power supply
5. **Smaller, and neater form factor**.  The A+ board is about 2cm shorter than the A, and has had the composite video moved to a 3.5mm four pin jack.

If you're aiming for a low powered device that needs to fit in a smaller space, or you need a hat ([because who doesn't love hats?](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)), the A+ is probably the better bet.

[Model A](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-a/):
[image]

[Model A+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-a-plus/):
[image]

Comment: Also note that it has mounting holes which allow it to be used with standard HAT boards

Comment: @angussidney: that is a great point. I have edited mention of the hats with a link to the RPi foundation's page :)

Comment: It would seem that HATs are not only mechanically supported but that the A+ also features the I2C identification scheme for the HAT's EEPROM.

Comment: @Ghanima: also addressed.

Answer (score 5):

The raspberry pi A+ is smaller, so you can fit it in smaller spaces. It depends on what I was doing, but I would probably choose the A+, given it has more GPIO pins.